# Flutter - Setting the body of a Scaffold

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using the Scaffold to change the body content, however it doesn't work when a Widget of the same class is already in the body.

If I'm currently on my home page and I try change to my new page, it works fine (I even pass parameters into the new page for initialization). However, if I'm already on my new page and I try change onto a different instance of the new page with different initialization variables it does not update.

```
onTap: () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      setState(() {
        AddState.circuitName = circuit.name;
        AddState.activities = circuit.activities;
        _body = _addPage;
      });
    }



class CircuitMaker extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  createState() => CircuitMakerState(AddState.activities, AddState.circuitName);

  CircuitMaker();


}
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @F-1 I've added some code, the first onTap function is put a listview for each tile and the Circuit Maker uses it to create its state. This will work if _body = _homePage, however it does not work if the _body = _addPage.